# For sklearn GridSearchCV, how can you guarantee classes will be represented in each fold's training set?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

When doing LogisticRegression with outputs of 0 and 1 and using GridSearchCV with 5-fold cross validation, I get:

```
ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: False
```

This clearly occurs because there are a smaller number of True or 1 values in the data split I am working with for this particular classifier.  If a split is chosen such that the train set only has 0's as above, it seems to be a wasted fold in that the classifier will return nan for the score.

Is there any way that I can guarantee that every training split will contain both classes?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Stratified K-fold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html). This will maintain the relative percentage of classes between folds.

Comment: I was looking at that, but was not quite sure.  The only question I would have is on "rounding".  So I guess for an 80/20 split, even if there was just one case of that class in the entire data set, 4/5 of 1 = 0.8 which should/would be rounded up to 1 guaranteeing that that same example would always be present in all training splits?

Comment: If you use the cv parameter with an integer value the documentation claims that the StratifiedKFold method will be used for cross validation.  However, I still get `ValueError('Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.')` which shows that it is not doing the trick.  I suppose you need a minimum of 2 values for each class and 1 has to be in the train split and 1 in the test split or else it won't work?

Comment: The data points will not be reused. If a fold is missing a class it won't take another datapoint elsewhere. Regarding the number of data points you need, depends on the number of folds you have. Say you have 5 folds you will need 5 of the minority class (one to go in each fold). If the counts of the minority class is significantly less than the majority class, I would re-frame the problem and use anomly detection models.

Comment: Thanks, yes, my problems fits into that.  I have a multilabel problem and so I model as individual binary classifiers.  In cases I do have < 5 positive examples of the class, so n-fold won't quite work.  Anomaly detection or perhaps oversampling.  Right now I fall back into a balanced weighting version of Logistic Regression if GridSearchCV throws and exception.